# Return a certain Object's value based on finding the Object in the array with another value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Tech being used: js, jquery, angular, and underscore. I have an array of Objects 0-4.  Each object has 2 value pairs "num: it's value" and "text : it's value".  So...

```
var arr = [
    {
        num: '1',
        text: 'First Place'
    },
    {
        num: '2',
        text: 'Second place'
    },
    ...
];
```

Now I have the have the num of the selected object, but I need to switch to the text.

This is working - "object 0 | num : 1" is selected store 1 in variable (selectedNum). How do I code based on selectedNum find the object that has 1 and return text of said object to variable selectedText.

Prefered answer using underscore.js.

Comment: In this case you would have to loop over the array of objects until you find an object with the matching num. underscore likely has a helper method that makes it easier, but behind the scenes that's all it's doing

Comment: *"Prefered answer using underscore.js."* Consider reading their documentation, since that's why it  exists.

Comment: @squint I did look at their documentation... it didn't really give me any take aways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[findWhere](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) will do it:

> Looks through the list and returns the first value that matches all of
>   the key-value pairs listed in properties.

```
var selectedNum = 3;
var selectedText = _.findWhere(arr, { num: selectedNum }).text;
```

**Update:**

You can also use find (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/net_uk_sweet/gJPHw/266/)).

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally - http://jsfiddle.net/gJPHw/262/

I still would like to have it solved using ._find, but this works.

```
var arrayOfFun = [
    { name:"string 1", code:"1" },
    { name:"string 2", code:"2" }
];

var selectedKey = arrayOfFun.filter(function ( selectedKey ) {
    return selectedKey.code === '1';
})[0];

console.log(selectedKey.name);
```

Comment: See updated answer with fiddle demonstrating use of underscore's find.